# Simple Mysql stored procedure with OUT parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE UserNameExists (IN pUserName VARCHAR(40), OUT rVal BIT)  
LANGUAGE SQL  
DETERMINISTIC  
BEGIN  
    SET @recCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE userName = pUserName);
    IF @recCount > 0 THEN 
        SET rVal := 1;
    ELSE 
        SET rVal := 0;
    END IF;    
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is how I call it:

```
USE MyDatabase;

CALL UserNameExists('sampleUser', @outputParam);

Select @outputParam;
```

I get a null row as a result, what is missing here?

Comment: how many records are there with `userName = sampleUser`?

Comment: can you do `SET @outputParam =0;` before calling the procedure?